# Convert number in textview to int

Tags: java, android, textview, int, type-conversion

So, I am messing around with java/android programming and right now I am trying to make a really basic calculator.  I am hung up on this issue though.  This is the code I have right now for getting the number thats in the textview and making it an int

```
CharSequence value1 = getText(R.id.textView);
int num1 =  Integer.parseInt(value1.toString());
```

And from what I can tell it is the second line that is causing the error, but im not sure why it is doing that.  It is compiling fine, but when it tries to run this part of the program it crashes my app.  And the only thing thats in the textview is numbers

Any advice?

I can also provide more of my code if necessary

Comment: Advice: read (and post) the error.

Comment: can you share a more detailed code?

Comment: and post the value that returns from `getText()` as well

Answer (score 19):

You can read on the usage of [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

How to declare it:

```
TextView tv;
```

Initialize it:

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

or:

```
tv = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
```

or, if you are inflating a layout,

```
tv = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

To set a string to `tv`, use `tv.setText(some_string)` or `tv.setText("this_string")`. If you need to set an integer value, use `tv.setText("" + 5)` as setText() is an overloaded method that can handle string and int arguments.

To get a value from `tv` use `tv.getText()`.

Always check if the parser can handle the possible values that `textView.getText().toString()` can supply. A `NumberFormatException` is thrown if you try to parse an empty string(""). Or, if you try to parse `.`.

```
String tvValue = tv.getText().toString();

if (!tvValue.equals("") && !tvValue.equals(......)) {
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(tvValue);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findviewbyID(R.id.textView);
int num = Integer.valueOf(tv.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Don't forget to catch the exception, as the text in TextView might not be a valid number.

Comment: Like Gaurav said:
int num = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());

Answer (score 2):

Here is the kotlin version :

```
var value = textview.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findviewbyID(R.id.textView);
String text = tv.getText().toString();
int n;
if(text.matches("\\d+")) //check if only digits. Could also be text.matches("[0-9]+")
{
   n = Integer.parseInt(text);
}
else
{
   System.out.println("not a valid number");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this code actually works better:

```
//this code to increment the value in the text view by 1

TextView quantityTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        CharSequence v1=quantityTextView.getText();
        int q=Integer.parseInt(v1.toString());
        q+=1;
        quantityTextView.setText(q +"");


//I hope u like this
```